# NiceMock a Mock that has another Mock as a constructor parameter

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I want to use a Mock with a NiceMock. The Mock has one constructor that takes another Mock as an argument. This is a small example of code that I have that works

```
class ClassA
{
    ClassA() { }
};

template <class T>
class ClassB>
{
    ClassB(ClassA & a) { } // constructor, no default constructor for this class
};

class ClassC
{
    ClassC() { }
};

class MyTest : public Test
{
    MockClassA a;
    MockClassB<ClassC> * b = NULL;

    SetUp()
    {
        b = new MockClassB<ClassC>(a);
    }
    ...
};
```

That works fine, but if I try use MockClassB with a NiceMock like this

```
MockClassA a;
NiceMock<MockClassB<ClassC>> * b = NULL;

SetUp()
{
    b = new NiceMock<MockClassB<ClassC>>(a);
}
```

I get a compile error saying `cannot convert argument 1 from 'const MockClassA' to 'ClassA &'`. Note that the error is on ClassA, which is the type of the argument to the constructor for ClassB. It doesn't help to wrap ClassA in a NiceMock like `NiceMock<MockClassA> a`, I just get a similar error: `cannot convert argument 1 from 'const testing::NiceMock<MockClassA>' to 'ClassA &'`

I have other templated classes that I'm using with NiceMock that work, but they don't have any constructor parameters.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem here, which I also faced, was that the parameter to the constructor was a non-const reference. I suggest updating the title to indicate that the problem was a non-const reference parameter. That will help people searching for this problem find the helpful answer easier. Thanks for asking this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument in `ClassB` constructor is a non-const reference to `ClassA`, which is not allowed in `NiceMock`. According to [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#the-nice-the-strict-and-the-naggy), one of the limitation is:

> The constructors of the base mock (MockFoo) cannot have arguments passed by non-const reference

To make it work, pass a const reference instead

```
ClassB(const ClassA & a) { }
```

or pass a pointer to `ClassA`

```
ClassB(ClassA * a) { }
```